# Как добавить в HashMap метод для ImageView?

Tags: java, android, java-ee, activity, android-sdk

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayList;
HashMap<String,Object> hashMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    arrayList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    CreateHashMap();

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,arrayList,R.layout.item,
            new String[]{"TEXT","IMAGE"},new int[]{R.id.textView,R.id.imageView});

    ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

public void CreateHashMap(){
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hashMap.put("TEXT", "asdadasdadsa");
        hashMap.put("IMAGE", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        arrayList.add(hashMap);
    }
}
}
```

Как добавить в HashMap ключ, который бы позволял указать размер Width для IMAGE?

Думал-думал, ничего не придумал, может, вы что подкините?

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Почему в

```
class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int      resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, int value) {
        super.setViewImage(v, value);
        Log.e("asd","asd");
    }
}
```

setViewImage вызывается 20 раз, если я создаю 5 объектов, и вызывается 40 раз, если я создаю 10 объектов? Это нормально? Или так не должно быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте класс, который бы хранил нужные данные для элемента списка, и не извращайтесь с этими костылями с Map'ами

Comment: @metalurgus, Ни слова не понял.

Comment: @Futurama, ну вы храните все нужные данные для каждого элемента списка в хешмепе. Вместо этого создайте класс, который будет содержать все нужные данные.